# Stirling Binomial Polynomial

Tags: polynomials, binomial-coefficients, stirling-numbers

Let $\{\cdot\}$ denote Stirling Numbers of the second kind. Let $(\cdot)$ denote the usual binomial coefficients. It is known that $$\sum_{j=k}^n {n\choose j} \left\{\begin{matrix} j \\ k \end{matrix}\right\} = \left\{\begin{matrix} n+1 \\ k+1 \end{matrix}\right\}.$$ Note: The indexes for $j$ aren't really needed since the terms are zero when $j>n$ or $j<k$.

How do I calculate $$\sum_{j=k}^n 4^j{n\choose j} \left\{\begin{matrix} j \\ k \end{matrix}\right\} = ?$$ I have been trying to think of this sum as some special polynomial (maybe a Bell polynomial of some kind) that has been evaluated at 4.

I have little knowledge of Stirling Numbers in the context of polynomials. Any help would be appreciated; even a reference to a comprehensive book on Stirling Numbers and polynomials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears we  can give another derivation of the  closed form by @vadim123 for the
sum $$q_n = \sum_{j=k}^n m^j {n\choose j} {j \brace k}$$
using the bivariate generating function of the Stirling numbers of the
second kind. This computation illustrates generating function techniques as presented in Wilf's *generatingfunctionology* as well as the technique of *annihilating coefficient extractors.*

Recall the species for set partitions which is
$$\mathfrak{P}(\mathcal{U} \mathfrak{P}_{\ge 1}(\mathcal{Z}))$$
which gives the generating function
$$G(z, u) = \exp(u(\exp(z)-1)).$$

Introduce the generating function
$$Q(z) = \sum_{n\ge k} q_n \frac{z^n}{n!}.$$

We thus have
$$Q(z) = \sum_{n\ge k} \frac{z^n}{n!}
\sum_{j=k}^n m^j {n\choose j} {j \brace k}.$$

Substitute $G(z, u)$ into the sum to get
$$Q(z) = \sum_{n\ge k} \frac{z^n}{n!}
\sum_{j=k}^n m^j {n\choose j} 
j! [z^j] \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^k}{k!}
\\ = \sum_{j\ge k} m^j \left([z^j] \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^k}{k!}\right)
\sum_{n\ge j} j!  \frac{z^n}{n!} {n\choose j}
\\ = \sum_{j\ge k} m^j \left([z^j] \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^k}{k!}\right)
\sum_{n\ge j}  \frac{z^n}{(n-j)!}
\\= \sum_{j\ge k} m^j \left([z^j] \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^k}{k!}\right)
z^j \sum_{n\ge j}  \frac{z^{n-j}}{(n-j)!}
\\ = \exp(z)
\sum_{j\ge k} m^j z^j \left([z^j] \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^k}{k!}\right).$$
Observe that the sum annihilates the coefficient extractor, producing
$$Q(z) = \exp(z)\frac{(\exp(mz)-1)^k}{k!}.$$
Extracting coefficients from $Q(z)$ we get
$$q_n = \frac{n!}{k!} 
[z^n] \exp(z) 
\sum_{q=0}^k {k\choose q} (-1)^{k-q} \exp(mqz)
\\ = \frac{n!}{k!} 
[z^n] \sum_{q=0}^k {k\choose q} (-1)^{k-q} \exp((mq+1)z)
= \frac{n!}{k!} 
\sum_{q=0}^k {k\choose q} (-1)^{k-q} \frac{(mq+1)^n}{n!}
\\ = \frac{1}{k!} 
\sum_{q=0}^k {k\choose q} (-1)^{k-q} (mq+1)^n.$$

Note that when $m=1$ $Q(z)$ becomes
$$\exp(z)\frac{(\exp(z)-1)^k}{k!}
= \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^{k+1}}{k!}
+ \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^k}{k!}$$
so that
$$[z^n] Q(z) = (k+1){n\brace k+1} + {n\brace k}
= {n+1\brace k+1},$$
which can also be derived using a very simple combinatorial argument.

**Addendum.**

Here is another derivation of the formula for $Q(z).$
Observe that when we  multiply two exponential generating functions of
the sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ we get that
$$ A(z) B(z) = \sum_{n\ge 0} a_n \frac{z^n}{n!} 
\sum_{n\ge 0} b_n \frac{z^n}{n!}
= \sum_{n\ge 0} 
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}\frac{1}{(n-k)!} a_k b_{n-k} z^n\\
= \sum_{n\ge 0} 
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} a_k b_{n-k} \frac{z^n}{n!}
= \sum_{n\ge 0} 
\left(\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} a_k b_{n-k}\right)\frac{z^n}{n!}$$
i.e. the  product of  the two generating  functions is  the generating
function of $$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} a_k b_{n-k}.$$
(I have included this derivation in several of my posts.)

Now in the present case we have
$$A(z) = \sum_{j\ge k} {j\brace k} m^j \frac{z^j}{j!}
\quad\text{and}\quad
B(z) = \sum_{j\ge 0} \frac{z^j}{j!} = \exp(z).$$

Evidently $A(z)$  is just the exponential generating  function for set
partitions into $k$ sets evaluated at $mz,$ so we get
$$A(z) = \frac{(\exp(mz)-1)^k}{k!}$$
and with $Q(z) = A(z) B(z)$ the formula for $Q(z)$ follows.

Answer (score 1):

This is as far as I got; for small $n$ or small $k$ I can work out what this is.

$$\sum_j 4^j{n\choose j} \left\{\begin{matrix} j \\ k \end{matrix}\right\}=$$

$$\sum_j 4^j{n\choose j} \frac{1}{k!}\sum_i(-1)^{k-i}{k\choose i} i^j=$$

$$\sum_i  \frac{1}{k!}(-1)^{k-i}{k\choose i} \sum_j (4i)^j{n\choose j} =$$

$$\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\sum_i  (-1)^{i}{k\choose i} (4i+1)^n $$

Comment: That looks interesting. It should also be noted that we can assume $n > k$ since the sum is zero otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

One can continue vadim123's approach with the ideas presented here ([A sum with binomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/386899/a-sum-with-binomial-coefficients/395528#395528)).

Comment: Alas, this is only effective if $n-k$ is small.